# How can I call an element that was declared in OPTION.html page in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have an element that is declared in Option.html file and been saved to chrome storage in Option.js. I want to access the value of that element so that I can use it in my Content.js. Any possible way?

I tried calling the element by its ID in Content.js, but it didn't work! It gives "Cannot read property 'value' of null", so I assume it's not reading the element (as it's not in the same file).

Here is what I have:

Option.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>My Test Extension Options</title></head>
<body>

waiting time:
<select id="waitingTime">
 <option value="oneMin">1 minute</option>
 <option value="TwoMin">2 minutes</option>
 <option value="FourMin">4 minutes</option>
 <option value="FiveMin">5 minutes</option>
</select>

<div id="status"></div>
<button id="save">Save</button>

<script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Option.js:

```
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function save_options() {
  var color = document.getElementById('waitingTime').value;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    favoriteColor: waitingTime,
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}
```

Content.js (where I call the element):

```
....
//the line I'm calling the element
var timeout = document.getElementById('waitingTime').value;
....
```

Manifest.json (I added option as well as permission):

```
....
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Build an Extension!",
"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab"],
"options_page": "options.html",
....
```

I would appreciate if you help me find a way accessing "waitingTime" value from content.js file! (or any alternative solution that serves the purpose).

Comment: The option page is a separate page which cannot be accessed directly from the content script. What you can do is use chrome.storage.local to save the values in the options page and read the value in the content script. You already save the value, now just read it: chrome.storage.sync.get({favoriteColor: 100}, data => { var timeout = data.favoriteColor; /* use timeout here inside the callback */ })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've saved your value into Chrome Storage from `options`, so now you just need to read it from there. Because `content script` and `option` are in different context so all we have to do is find a place that these 2 context can connect to, in this case is `Chrome Storage`. Like so:

**options.js**

```js
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function save_options() {
  var color = document.getElementById('waitingTime').value;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    favoriteColor: waitingTime,
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}
```

**content-script.js**

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get('favoriteColor', function(result) {
    if (result && result.favoriteColor) {
        // You can use it here: result.favoriteColor
    }
});
```

One thing I want to mention is `chrome.storage.sync` and `chrome.storage.local`, you might know it already but just in case.

- `chrome.storage.sync`, sync data between Chrome browsers which you use your account to login to sync browsing data, this has a reading/writing [limitation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#properties)
- `chrome.storage.local` won't sync the data, basically it just store your data on the browser which you've installed the extension. This function has storage size limitation (only can store maximum `5,242,880` bytes), you can read [this document](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-local) to increase it.